# Clone contenteditable div without text

Tags: javascript, html

How can I clone a new row without also copying the text that has been inserted inside the contenteditable div? I want a new blank div to type into. Many thanks

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="row">
    <div id="left">
      <p><strong>Heading</strong></p>
      <div contenteditable="true" data-placeholder="Type here...">
    </div>
    <div id="right">
      <p><strong>Heading</strong></p>
      <div contenteditable="true" data-placeholder="Type here...">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<button id="button" onlick="duplicate()">Add another row</button>
```

```
document.getElementById('button').onclick = duplicate;

var i = 0;
var original = document.getElementById('row');

function duplicate() {
    var clone = original.cloneNode(true);
    clone.id = "row" + ++i;
    original.parentNode.appendChild(clone);
}
```

Comment: So replace the innerHTML of the element

Comment: Why not simply use `document.createElement` instead of cloning?

Comment: @epascarello how? I don't know how to write JS

Comment: @redibis `clone.innerHTML = ''`

Comment: @kmoser doesn't seem to work or I'm doing it wrong

Comment: You would need to select the element that is contenteditable, not the row

Comment: @redibis Whoops, right, you need to set the innerHTML of the contenteditable div, not of the row.

Comment: @kmoser do you know how to solve my last comment in the answer below? I'm still trying. Thank you

Comment: @redibis if you're still using parts of the OP code, then you probably still have problems. `#id` will hinder you, see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70513759/2813224).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Recommendations**

- Do not assign `#id`s to anything that would be duplicated use `.class` and `.querySelector()`. It's actually a better practice not to use `#id` at all since it will become increasingly difficult to adapt your code in the future. There are exceptions when it is actually an advantage rather than a hinderance (ex. checkboxes/radiobuttons association with labels).
- When [handling events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/Event_handlers), do not use on event attributes -- instead, use on event properties or `.addEventListener()` to handle events such as "click". It appears that in the OP code on event attribute and property was used to handle the same click event.

> ```
> <!-- Do not use this --> <button id="button" onlick="duplicate()">
> <!-- Use this:  listenerElement.onclick = duplicate
>      or this: listenerElement.addEventListener('click', duplicate)
>   -->
> ```

- Add event handlers (ex. `duplicate()`) with on event property (ex. `.onclick`) or with `.addEventListener()` on a parent element of all elements that need an event handler. So instead of each button listening for a user to click it -- have `div#wrapper` (in example below it is `main`) listen for a user to click a button. It's strongly recommended that you familiarize yourself with **[event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation)**.

Keeping what was previously mentioned in mind, the following example has:

- all `#id`s replaced by `.class`.
- the `onclick="duplicate()"` removed from button
- the event handler (renamed `addRow(e)`) uses `.insertAdjacentHTML()` to render a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) of `section.row` behind the `section.row` of the `button.addRow` that the user clicked. ***Details are commented in the example below***
- the event handler added to `main` in order to delegate click events for all buttons present when page has been loaded as well as any buttons added dynamically in the future

> ```
> document.querySelector('main').onclick = addRow;
> ```

- some CSS added and some minor changes to HTML for semantics and styling

***Details are commented in the example below**
Note: it wasn't clear whether it was one button or a button on every row. This example is designed for the latter. Please comment below if the former (a single button) is desired.*

```js
// Pass the Event Object
const addRow = event => {
  // This is the tag user has clicked
  const btn = event.target;
  // This is the string that will be rendered
  const tmp = `<section class="row"><div class="left part"><header>Heading</header><div contenteditable>Type here...</div></div><div class="right part"><header>Heading</header><div contenteditable>Type here...</div></div><button class="addRow">Add Row</button></section>`;
  // This is the row of the tag user has clicked
  let ref = btn.parentElement;
  // if this tag has class .addRow...
  if (btn.matches('.addRow')) {
   /*
   ... render a string (tmp) after the 
   row of the clicked button (ref) into HTML 
   */
   ref.insertAdjacentHTML('afterEnd', tmp);
  }
};

document.querySelector('main').onclick = addRow;
```

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
.part {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  width: 42vw;
}
.right {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
button {
  display: block;
  width: max-content;
  margin-left: auto;
  padding: 2px 4px;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <section class="row">
    <div class="left part">
      <header>Heading</header>
      <div contenteditable>Type here...</div>
    </div>
    <div class="right part">
      <header>Heading</header>
      <div contenteditable>Type here...</div>
    </div>
    <button class='addRow'>Add Row</button>
  </section>
</main>
```

***The following example is designed with one button***

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <style>
    main {
      width: 100vw;
    }
    
    .box {
      width: 80vw;
      margin: 10px auto;
      padding: 5px;
      border: 2px solid black;
    }
    
    .row {
      display: flex;
      flex-flow: row nowrap;
      justify-content: flex-start;
      align-items: flex-start;
    }
    
    .part {
      display: flex;
      flex-flow: column nowrap;
      justify-content: flex-start;
      width: 36vw;
      margin: 4px auto;
    }
    
    .right {
      margin-left: 10px;
    }
    
    button {
      display: block;
      width: max-content;
      margin: 4px 30px 4px auto;
      padding: 2px 4px;
    }
    
    [data-ph]::before {
      content: attr(data-ph)
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <main>
    <div class="box">
      <section class="row">
        <div class="left part">
          <header>Heading</header>
          <div data-ph='Type here...' contenteditable></div>
        </div>
        <div class="right part">
          <header>Heading</header>
          <div data-ph='Type here...' contenteditable></div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
    <button class='addRow'>Add Row</button>

    <div class="box">
      <section class="row">
        <div class="left part">
          <header>Heading</header>
          <div data-ph='Type here...' contenteditable></div>
        </div>
        <div class="right part">
          <header>Heading</header>
          <div data-ph='Type here...' contenteditable></div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
    <button class='addRow'>Add Row</button>
  </main>

  <script>
    const addRow = event => {
      const btn = event.target;
      const tmp = `<section class="row"><div class="left part"><header>Heading</header><div data-ph="Type here..." contenteditable></div></div><div class="right part"><header>Heading</header><div data-ph="Type here..." contenteditable></div></div></section>`;
      let ref = btn.previousElementSibling;
      if (btn.matches('.addRow')) {
        ref.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', tmp);
      }
    };
    document.querySelector('main').onclick = addRow;
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you. This is adding the new rows outsite the "wrapper" div I have. Can they be added just underneath the "row" div?

Comment: It's already adding the new row right underneath the row of the button the user clicked. In this [screenshot](https://i.ibb.co/n15GRXs/Screenshot-2021-12-29-004838.png) you can see that there's a secomd row highlighted in grey.

Comment: The `.left` in OP code is missing the end tag `</div>` which should be placed before `.right`.  Also the button isn't in the row it needs to sit right after `.right` and the end tag to `.wrapper` is missing as well. That's why I try to use more meaningful elements like `<main>` and `<section>` -- it breaks up the monotony of a ton of `<div>`s.

Comment: I got it working. May I ask if it's possible to only have one "add row" button outside the wrapper, rather than within each row itself? I tried to only have one button and it still works, but it adds the row in a different order. As you can see in [this image](https://i.ibb.co/D1pQDFH/Capture.jpg), after the second row, the next ones are added from the bottom up. The reason is that I am exporting the plain html of those rows, and if I leave the button inside it, it gets "printed" in the exported html, which I don't want. Thank you

Comment: So you want the new row inserted under the last row? The placeholder must be from JavaScript from somewhere else . `data-placeholder` is a custom attribute that has no default HTML features so there should be a function in your source that places the value into the `<div>`. I just thought of how it's done by CSS, but if you want it to behave as a true placeholder you'll still need to use JavaScript. If you can't figure it out you'll need to post another question. Standby for an update on this answer.

Comment: The placeholder is fine just needed some CSS. Yes I would like to have only one button outside the wrapper, adding each row underneath the other. I mean I do like the button with each row, but I assume there is no way to then exclude the button from the exported text/html. Thank you

Comment: @redibis answer is updated. I added the CSS to second example and on the first example I just placed the text in the `<div>` itself -- as far as I can tell it's the same result. Don't forget to accept this answer if it resolved your problem.

Comment: Thank you. It appends the new rows before the end of another `<main>` tag in the page. Can I target the specific `<main>` of that block or change it to a `<div>` ID? The placeholder now does not disappear when typing?

Comment: I've fixed the placeholder behaviour using `[data-ph]:empty:before` in the CSS

Comment: So you have multiple "wrappers"? `<main>` is supposed to be only one per page. No, `#id`s are last resort. If the placeholder actually behaved like a real placeholder then you have either a plugin or some JavaScript you are not aware of. Standby for update.

Comment: Yeah well it's a functionality within a page so there is already a `<main>` tag. I have the page content and then that functionality as part of it.

Comment: Got it! I can now target the ID this way `document.querySelector('[id="ID"]').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', tmp);`

Comment: If you really need to use `#id` the proper syntax is: `document.querySelector('#ID')`. See the updated example it's much more generic so you never need to use `#id`. Writing generic code is a good practice because it'll be easier to modify, reuse, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You need to select the contenteditable elment and replace the html

```
function duplicate() {
    var clone = original.cloneNode(true);
    clone.id = "row" + ++i;
    clone.querySelector('div[contenteditable="true"]').innerHTML = '';    
    original.parentNode.appendChild(clone);
}
```

because you now said it is more than one, you need querySelectorAll

```
function duplicate() {
  var clone = original.cloneNode(true);
  clone.id = "row" + ++i;
  clone.querySelectorAll('div[contenteditable="true"]').forEach(function(elem) {
    elem.innerHTML = '';
  });
  original.parentNode.appendChild(clone);
}
```

Comment: I don't know how to make that work... What I tried didn't work but I can't write JS so might be me

Comment: The line goes right in  your function.....

Comment: Oh ok. In my actual version I have the row with 2 headings and 2 contenteditable divs, each pair inside its own div. Can I clone the whole content of that "row" div? Now it's only cloning half of it. Thank you! Almost there

Comment: So if the HTML s different of course it will not work.... I changed the selector a bit.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't know that would make a difference. I thought I would just clone the whole "row" div. I can edit the question

Comment: Great! The first div on the left works, the div on the right still retains the text inside the contenteditable div (I've updated the question html)

Comment: So that is why you need to show all your code.... One vs many is different. Edited it to use querySelectorAll and a loop